# INVALID_FIELD error on User.ProfileId for Salesforce Platform User

Tags: apex, permissions, profile, standard-objects, userlicense

We have a running application that has a custom lightning component to create partner users. User is successfully created in the context of System Admin. But when trying to create a partner user in the context of a salesforce platform user, we get an INVALID_FIELD error on the ProfileId field of the user.

After looking into existing questions, I found that "View Setup and Configuration" permission is required to access a profile on the user object. Even after enabling the permission on the profile level, the User gets the same INVALID_FIELD error for the profileId field of the user object.

Is there any other permission required to access profileId field of User object?

Comment: Try adding System permission > **Manage User** to your permission set

Comment: We can not add 'Manage Users' permission to the profiles having Salesforce Platform user license.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this steps:

- Navigate to the specific user details in Salesforce
- Go to `Permission Set License Assignment` of that user
- Assign `Salesforce API Integration` which contains "Manage Users" in the permission which will give the "View Setup and Configuration" permission also

[image: Permission Set License]